# Material-UI Autocomplete event.target

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I use Autocomplete component and I have code like this:

```
const countries = [
    {country: 'Poland', code: 'PL'},
    {country: 'Germany', code: 'DE'},
    {country: 'Spain', code: 'ES'},
    {country: 'France', code: 'FR'}
]

const Input = ({onCountryChange}) => (
    <Autocomplete
    id="combo-box"
    options={countries}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.country}
    style={{ width: 300, marginTop: 10 }}
    onChange={onCountryChange}
    renderInput={params => (
      <TextField {...params} label="Type a country" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
    )}
    />
)
```

```
onCountryChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      countryCode: event.target.textContent
    });
  };
```

Now it sets as `countryCode` the country from countries options and I would like to use code instead (like PL). Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost got the answer. I changed the `onCountryChange` function and look if this what you seek.

here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-mccarthy-kqx97

```
const countries = [
  { country: "Poland", code: "PL" },
  { country: "Germany", code: "DE" },
  { country: "Spain", code: "ES" },
  { country: "France", code: "FR" }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    countryCode: ""
  };

  onCountryChange = (object, value) => {
    this.setState({
      countryCode: value.code
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { countryCode } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {countryCode}
        <Autocomplete
          id="combo-box"
          options={countries}
          getOptionLabel={option => option.country}
          style={{ width: 300, marginTop: 10 }}
          onChange={this.onCountryChange}
          renderInput={params => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label="Type a country"
              variant="outlined"
              fullWidth
            />
          )}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Material UI documentation:

`function(event: React.SyntheticEvent, value: T | Array<T>, reason: string, details?: string) => void`

- event: The event source of the callback.
- value: The new value of the
- component. reason: One of "createOption", "selectOption",
  "removeOption", "blur" or "clear".

This is my onChange function from [Grouped template](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#grouped) with TypeScript:

```
onChange={(event, value, reason, details) => selectChangeHandler(event, value as { title: string, year: number, firstLetter: string }, reason, details)}

const selectChangeHandler = (event: SyntheticEvent, value: { title: string, year: number, firstLetter: string }, reason: string, details: unknown) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('value', value)
    console.log('reason', reason)
    console.log('details', details)
  }
```